# Comma separated text instead of multiple selection on Django Form for Many to Many Field

Tags: python, html, django, forms, filter

So, I'm developing a web application to control the inventory on my company in Django (yes, I know there are plenty open source alternatives out there, we are in fact using fusioninventory right now, but I'm not the boss...).

The thing is, one computer can have multiple users, and so I implemented it on the model as a ManyToMany field. Here is the relevant code for the model, filter and html template. Note that I'm using django_filters lib to implement the search filters and widget_tweaks to give some style to the form.

**models.py**

```
class Computer(models.Model):
    tag = models.CharField(max_length = 20, unique=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank = True, default = 'No_User',)
    TYPE = (
    ('DESK','Desktop'),
    ('LAP','Laptop'),
    )
    computertype = models.CharField(
        max_length = 4,
        choices = TYPE,
    )
    STATUS = (
    ('OK','OK'),
    ('Broken','Broken'),
    ('Unusable','Unusable'),
    )
    computerstatus = models.CharField(
        max_length = 12,
        choices = STATUS,
        default = 'OK',
    )
    model = models.CharField(max_length = 36)
    serial = models.CharField(max_length = 36)
    buy_date = models.DateField()
    modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.tag
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('computer_detail', args=[str(self.id)])
```

**filters.py**

```
class UserFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = {
            'username': ['contains'],
        }

class ComputerFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tag = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr="icontains",label = 'Etiqueta',)
    computertype = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices = Computer.TYPE, lookup_expr="icontains",label = 'Tipo',)
    computerstatus = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(choices = Computer.STATUS, lookup_expr="icontains",label = 'Estado',)
    **users = UserFilter()**
    from = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='buy_date', lookup_expr="gt", label='Adquiridos desde',)
    to = django_filters.DateFilter(field_name='buy_date', lookup_expr="lt", label='Hasta',)
    class Meta:
        model = Computer
        fields = ['tag','users','computertype','computerstatus',]
```

**computer_list.html**

```
  <form method="get">
    <div class="well">
      <center><h4><b>Filtro</b></h4></center>
      <center><table>
      <tr>
        <td><div class"form-group">
          {{ filter.form.tag.label_tag}}
          {% render_field filter.form.tag class="form-control" %}
        </div></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class"form-group">
          {{ filter.form.computertype.label_tag}}
          {% render_field filter.form.computertype class="form-control" %}
        </div></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><div class"form-group">
          {{ filter.form.computerstatus.label_tag}}
          {% render_field filter.form.computerstatus class="form-control" %}
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class"form-group">
          {{ filter.form.desde.label_tag}}
          {% render_field filter.form.desde class="form-control" type="date" %}
        </div></td>
        <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
        <td><div class"form-group">
          {{ filter.form.hasta.label_tag}}
          {% render_field filter.form.hasta class="form-control" type="date" %}
        </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><div class"form-control" input type ="text">
          {{ filter.form.users.label_tag}}
          {% render_field filter.form.users class="form-control" %}
        </div></td>
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table></center>
      <div>
      <p> </p><center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Buscar
      </button></center>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

You can see the full code [on github](https://github.com/PedroSoriano/inventory-manager)

Right now the filter form looks like this:
[See the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulHO8.png)

**Question:** Is there an easy way so that the form field would accept input like:
user1, user2, ... , usern instead of selecting the users?

**Bonus:** Is there a way to implement it so that it also has autocomplete (I write for example, - user1, use - and it shows me all the users begining with "use" so I can click it and it gets added to the field.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I believe you are looking for something like Select2 ~ https://github.com/applegrew/django-select2

Answer (score 0):

you can user ModelMultipleChoiceField

```
users = ModelMultipleChoiceField()
```